# Using multiple test interfaces on the same test program?

Tags: origen-sdk

When trying to modular-ize an [Origen test interface](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/interface), which of the following methods is best?

1) Create a base test interface that other child test interfaces inherit from, which gets called from sub-flow files

2) Create a single interface class and use mixin modules to handle specific test modules

thx

Answer (score 0):

Definitely option (2) is the way to go, this will make it easier to include pre-written interface helpers from multiple sources in future.

e.g. we are starting to develop an Origen V93K std library and in time we will provide an interface mixin to generate tests that use it, and you will likely also develop your own libraries within your company that you will want to mixin too.

See the example at the bottom of this section where there is an interface which includes a `MyLibrary` mixin, that's how you want to setup an interface:
http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/v93k/#Distribute_as_a_Plugin

Comment: thanks for the comments and the link, coding will now begin :)